# Inserting into a database but it says the table does not exist

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am making a program with a login system whereby a user can create a username and password which will be inserted into a database, in the "Account" table. However when I run the program and try to create a username and password, the program says that the table "Account" does not exist.
How do I fix this?

```
            create = input("Would you like to create an account or re-enter Username?\nEnter 1 to re-enter, Enter 2 to create ")
            if create == "1":
                set_up()
            if create == "2":
                New_Username = input("Enter a username: ")
                New_Password = input("Enter a password: ")
                
                conn = sqlite3.connect('Database = NEA_quiz_database.db;'
                                      'Trusted_Connection = yes;')

                cursor = conn.cursor()

                cursor.execute("""
                                INSERT INTO Account (UserID, Password)
                                VALUES(New_Username, New_Password)
                                """)
                conn.commit()
```

[Account table in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlmFD.png)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FQjX.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's the same database, i.e. you use the same path for both the files?

Comment: could be any number of things, but most likely that the table does not exist, or is in a different schema, or you don't have permissions for it.  Account may be a reserved word, try using [Account].  Finally and MOST IMPORTANT!  SQL statements in an EXECUTE command are a primary source of injection attack.  At least look at parameterisation, but better still make all inserts and updates a call to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This `'Database = NEA_quiz_database.db;'` is a string literal (contained in single quotes/ticks, ie `'`) so the program is trying to connect to that file as the database file. The sqlite3 API will create the file if it is not found.  I will guess that you will find a file named `Database = NEA_quiz_database.db;` in the current working directory. The database name should be passed as a string to the [connect method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect). Something like:

`sqlite3.connect('NEA_quiz_database.db')`